# Laravel file upload image not working on hosting

Tags: forms, laravel

Help my code works on xampp and php artisan serve localhost:8000 
but in server hosting the validation fail. When I try to upload image it, returns `Errors: The image field is required.`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{  
 $this->validate($request, array(
         'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,png,bmp|required|max:3000'
 ));

Session::flash('success', 'Image been uploaded.');  

return redirect()->route('galleries.index');
}
```

html

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'galleries.store', 'class' => 'form-inline', 'files' => true]) !!}

{!! Form::file('image', ['required' => '']) !!} 

{!! Form::submit('Upload', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Flash Data**
>
> Sometimes you may wish to store items in the session only for the next request. You may do so using the flash method. Data stored in the session using this method will only be available during the subsequent HTTP request, and then will be deleted. Flash data is primarily useful for short-lived status messages:

In this case you can use this source for upload file

```
$fileName = $this->getFileName($file);
$pathUpload = $this->createPath(sprintf('%s', $config['path']));
$media = $file->move($pathUpload, $fileName);

protected function createPath($paths)
{
    if (!is_array($paths)) {
        if (!\File::exists($paths)) {
            \File::makeDirectory($paths, $mode = 0777, true, true);
        }
    } else {
        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            if (!\File::exists($path)) {
                \File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);
            }
        }
    }
    return $paths;
}
```

Function `createPath` for create folder and set permission.

Function move using `file_put_content` method for upload your file